# Change value in gridview colums yii2

Tags: yii2

I have this in my view

```
'columns' => [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    [
        'attribute' => 'order_delivery_address_city',
        'value' => 'address.order_delivery_address_city'
    ],
```

which shows field like '1' or '2' or '3'... How to change it to be like this

```
if (address.order_delivery_address_city == '1') {
    'value' => 'New-York'
}
```

Comment: if `address` relation have relation with `city` then you can use `address.cityRleationName.city_table_field(for ex. city_name)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'attribute' => 'order_delivery_address_city',
            'value' => function($model){
                         if($model->address->order_delivery_address_city == '1'){
                            return 'New-York';
                         }
                       }
        ],
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
             [
                'attribute'=>'order_delivery_address_city',
                'value'=>function($model){
                  return $model->order_delivery_address_city=='1' ? 'New-York':'Anything else';
                }
            ],
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work fine. Try this way.

```html
'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'attribute' => 'order_delivery_address_city',
            'value' => function($model){
                $city_name = City::find()->select(['city_name'])->where(['city_id' => $model->order_delivery_address_city])->one();
                return $city_name ? $city_name->city_name:'None';
            },
        ],
```

It will look into **City** table and will search single record for matching **city_id** as contained in **order_delivery_address_city** and return the corresponding **city_name**. If no matching record found then it will return **None**.